# Multi-factor affine yield models reference (a la Duffie and Kan)

Tags: yield-curve, reference-request

http://www.darrellduffie.com/uploads/pubs/DuffieKan1996.pdf

I was trying to read above paper on the topic of multi-factor affine models, but I presume the contents have been dealt with more thoroughly in perhaps a textbook aimed at a broader audience. Does anybody know of such a reference?